# Adding text to pdf.js canvas before display

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas, pdf.js

Is it possible to add text to canvas before display it on page?

Cuz for now it like:

```
<canvas class="pdf-page-canvas" height="841" width="595"></canvas>
<canvas class="pdf-page-canvas" height="841" width="595"></canvas>
<canvas class="pdf-page-canvas" height="841" width="595"></canvas>
<canvas class="pdf-page-canvas" height="841" width="595"></canvas>
<canvas class="pdf-page-canvas" height="841" width="595"></canvas>
<canvas class="pdf-page-canvas" height="841" width="595"></canvas>
<canvas class="pdf-page-canvas" height="841" width="595"></canvas>
```

I tried to add div and span with text inside  tag, but it didn't display it. Also tried to add text to canvas

```
pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdf) {
thePdf = pdf;
viewer = document.getElementById('pdf-viewer');
        
for(page = 1; page <= pdf.numPages; page++) {
 canvas = document.createElement("canvas");    
 canvas.className = 'pdf-page-canvas';         
  viewer.appendChild(canvas);         
  renderPage(page, canvas);
 }
});
    
function renderPage(pageNumber, canvas) {
 thePdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
 viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });
 canvas.height = viewport.height;
 canvas.width = viewport.width;
 var gcc = canvas.getContext('2d');
 gcc.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
 gcc.fillStyle = "green";
 gcc.textAlign = "center";
 gcc.fillText("Hello World", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);           
 page.render({canvasContext: gcc, viewport: viewport});
 );
}
```

It just display normal pdf page with content on it, without any "Hello world" text on it in any part. What I'm doing wrong? Maybe I can parse canvas to html and them add text to it as normal tag? Or edit canvas as image-like object and update it with added text?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `page.render({canvasContext: gcc, viewport: viewport});` just clear the work you have done? Comment out it to do a quick verify.